# Cron Authentication Failure error in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ldap

I was bogged with an error “Authentication Failure” for all of my cron jobs in Linux Ubunutu.

```
root@Test:~# tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep cron
Dec 11 16:38:01 Test cron[14861]: Authentication failure
Dec 11 16:38:01 Test cron[14861]: Authentication failure
Dec 11 16:38:09 Test cron[14957]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Dec 11 16:38:09 Test cron[14957]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping@reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Dec 11 16:39:01 Test cron[14957]: Authentication failure
```

I try everything but didn't want work , I m using LDAP. Did someone had the same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

could you check the permission and ownership of the cron file for the user using to run the cron in /var/spool/cron/crontabs?

Also if the user account is locked? So please check the /etc/passwd file's entry for that user. It should not have expired or days set for password expiration. If that checks out fine, the you would want to see if the /etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny files are ok and do not contain the user which is running the cron. Seeing your reply, i believe its root user and i am hoping the allow and deny files are ok.

Next you would want to check /etc/security/access.conf and see if adding the below entry helps you or not

+ALL:cron crond

but make sure you have backed up the access.conf and the entry is added BEFORE/ABOVE 
-:ALL:ALL

Now if that also does not help, then you would need to check the authentication module you have configured in the system, kerberos, pan, ldap, which ever. I would suggest you go through the above drill and Let us know further.

Comment: I try everything but didn't want work , I m using ldap .

Comment: Is this issue resolved? Could you please provide the permissions on /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Answer (score 1):

check ownership of the cron file for the user using to run the cron in /var/spool/cron/crontabs.

```
-rw------- 1 root root 338 Dec  8 12:49 root
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it was caused by deleting a user and their crontab entry was not deleted at that time. Essentially, crontab can't run the command as the user as the user does not exist - so check that too!

Answer (score 1):

I've typically seen this if the user account has expired, which can happen for the root user as well.

To check, `su` to the user and check if you get `Authentication Failure`, e.g.:

```
$ sudo su -
Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator
su: Authentication failure
(Ignored)
```

**To fix**: update the expiration on the account:

```
sudo chage -M 300 root
```

Or whatever username you're having issues with in place of `root` above.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I turned up was when `pam_tally2` was setup. In `journalctl -u cron` I saw

```
May 26 08:12:01 PublicProxy CRON[16303]: pam_tally2(cron:setcred): bad number supplied: unlock_time=never
```

Here's the non-working line:

```
auth       required pam_tally2.so silent even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=never
```

Here's what it looks like when it's fixed:

```
auth       required pam_tally2.so silent even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue with below steps:

1. Please check if password of that user should not be expried.

   ```
   chage -l scfuser
   ```
2. If it's expired then set with below step:

   ```
   passwd scfuser
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).